# How can I query the range of date which one product has not been ordered? (LINQ)

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have three tables,

- Products(ProductID, ProductName)
- Orders(OrderID, OrderDate)
- OrderDetails(ProductID, OrderID) Junction table between Products and Orders.

For example, there are 
Three ProductID in Products table
A01, A02, A03

Four OrderID in Orders table
1. 01/01/2009, 2. 03/01/2009, 3. 05/01/2009, 4. 07/01/2009.

OrderDetails data
as below:

A01 --  01/01/2009

A02 --  01/01/2009

A01 --  03/01/2009

A02 --  03/01/2009

A01 --  05/01/2009

A03 --  05/01/2009

A01 -- 07/01/2009

then I want to display the date that A03 is not ordered from range 02/01/2009 till 08/01/2009 which could have the result like this.

**DateMissingOrder** for Product A03 in range of date 02/01/2009 to 08/01/2009:

03/01/2009

07/01/2009

How can I do this in LINQ to SQL Visual Basic? May someone help me with some clue please.. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

**Select all the dates in the range**

```
Dim DatesInRange = (From o in dc.Orders _
                   Where (o.OrderDate >= StartDate and _
                          o.OrderDate <= EndDate)
                   Select o.OrderDate).Distinct
```

**Select all the dates in the range for A03 orders**

```
Dim Dates = (From o in dc.OrdersDetails _
            Where (o.Order.OrderDate >= StartDate and _
                   o.Order.OrderDate <= EndDate) and _
                   o.Order.Product.ProductName = "A03" _
            Select o.Order.OrderDate).Distinct
```

**Return the dates missing from the second list**

```
Dim MissingDates = DatesInRange.Except(Dates)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.. but we're looking for the date missing date of the product name A03. In your case you are selecting only the product which is not A03.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! The problem is solved now!! You are the SMARTEST GUY IN THE WORLD !!!! THANKS